# How to get params from any Uri in Slim 3 Framework?

Tags: php, slim-3

I'm new to Slim 3 framework. I want to get the param such as api_key or token from any API URL to validate if the requested api_key is correct. (Any request API with any method sent to server will always have 2 parameters: a GET api_key and a POST token.)

In Slim 2 I am using `$app->request()->get('api_key')`, but `request()` has been removed in Slim 3. How can I get the parameters before it gets included into any route?

Comment: What does your code look like? Normally you have a request object for each route and therefore you can get the params through the request object.

Comment: `api_key` is a part of body or headers in your code?

Comment: @LLJ97 i want to get params from any request uri to server then check the param , if it's correct i will include the route to serve the request

Comment: @DrakulaPredator it's on the headers

Comment: So you want to check the params before the request gets executed? Have you looked at slims middleware? If not, that would be a good place to start.

Comment: @LLJ97 thanks for your advising, i will read through and see what can i do with that :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you're looking for an application middleware.

In slim 3 it could look like this:

```php
$app = new \slim\App();
$app->add(function($request, $response, $next) {
    // check if the header is set
    if ($request->getHeader('api_key')) {
        // check key
        if (key_is_valid($request->getHeader('api_key'))) { // dummy function
            return $next($request, $response);
        }
    }
});
```

This middleware checks every request for the api key and only executes the request if the key is valid.

Of course you have to implement some kind of error handling if the key is not valid.

Slim injects everything into the function parameters so that you can use it.

Comment: Yes I read through the middleware and did the same thing, now it work :D